# How can I check if an array is set and contains a value at the same time?

Tags: javascript

I need to check if ['pk'] is available in the first item in an array, and only then do some stuff. The array is not always populated, so I am ending up with a block of code that feels a little bit bloated.

How can I make this code shorter and nicer? I'm sure Javascript have a way to do this better... (without having a lot of errors in the console while the array is empty...)

```
var $selectedItem = $scope.selectedItem[0] || null;
if($selectedItem) {
  var $selectedPK = $selectedItem['pk'];
}
if($selectedPK) { ... }
```

Comment: `if($selectedItem && $selectedItem['pk'])`?

Comment: I don't think this question is specific enough.

Comment: @slhck if($scope.selectedItem[0] && $scope.selectedItem[0]['pk']) { ... }; worked like a charm, thanks! Write it up as a question and I will accept it :)

Comment: Specifically check to see if `$scope.selectedItem[0]['pk']` is undefined or that check will fail if `$scope.selectedItem[0]['pk'] === 0` ... have a look at my answer

Comment: It will also fail if pk === an empty string or null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's no further checking if the first part of the boolean *and* condition is `false`, this is much more concise:

```
if ($selectedItem && $selectedItem['pk']) {
  ...
}
```

I think you should be able to make the assignment in the condition right away:

```
if ($selectedItem && ($selectedPk = $selectedItem['pk'])) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could at least combine the two

```
var $selectedItem = $scope.selectedItem[0] || null;
if($selectedItem) {
  var $selectedPK = $selectedItem['pk'];
  if($selectedPK) { 
    ... 
  }
}
```

Comment: Doh.. Off course :) I didn’t polish my example code that much. However, the comment from slhck is the "answer" I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more ;)....

```
if ($scope.selectedItem[0] && $scope.selectedItem[0].pk!==undefined) {
 // do stuff
}
```